# Is Perl's Text::Fuzzy case sensitive

Tags: perl, fuzzy-logic

I'm using the [Text::Fuzzy](http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/Text-Fuzzy-0.24/lib/Text/Fuzzy.pod) module. The documentation doesn't mention if the string comparison is case sensitive. Anyone happen to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the [source code](https://github.com/benkasminbullock/Text-Fuzzy), it is case-**sensitive**. You can debug what the module is doing (at least the perl implementation) by setting `$Text::Fuzzy::verbose = 1` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but wondering if you can help me out. I also looked at the source code but could not follow it. The Perl code is here: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BKB/Text-Fuzzy-0.24/lib/Text/Fuzzy.pm. How does the C code get called? I don't quite follow how this module works.

Comment: The C code is compiled in the Perl way, using [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html). You can see the binding [here](https://github.com/benkasminbullock/Text-Fuzzy/blob/master/Fuzzy.xs), the actual build process is a bit involved but the core C functionality is [here](https://github.com/benkasminbullock/Text-Fuzzy/blob/master/edit-distance.c.tmpl). The important thing is: Text distance is calculated on edit distance of characters, without looking at the semantics of those characters, i.e. the distance between `a` and `b` is the same as between `a` and `A` is the same as between `a` and `ä`.